# Win32 Named pipe behavior

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

Win7, x64, C++, Win32 API, Console app, Visual Studio Community 2015

I've scoured all the SO questions on named pipes and can't find the answer I need.

I'm writing a server to broadcast data one way via named pipe to multiple identical clients on the same machine.  The sever and each client is in its own process (.exe).  The data is sent when *all* the clients have somehow signaled back to the server that they are ready (via named event or other mechanism).

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx) says multiple clients can connect to a single pipe instance, but then proceeds to talk about [multiple instances](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365594(v=vs.85).aspx).

I have a few questions about the pipe on the server side:

1. For a small number of clients and low throughput, which is the simplest: 1 thread, 1 pipe instance; 1 thread and multiple pipe instances; multiple threads and one instance per thread?
2. If a single thread does `ConnectNamedPipe` multiple times on the same instance of a pipe, does this mean a single `WriteFile` is broadcast to all clients that have connected to that particular instance of the pipe?
3. If multiple clients can connect to a particular instance of a pipe, does writing to that pipe from the server side block until *all* the clients have read the previous message?
4. Is doing a one-to-many situation uncommon?  Why?

Comment: *The documentation says multiple clients can connect to a single pipe instance* - no, you've misread and/or misunderstood it.  Each instance can support only a single client at a time.  (And to answer your question, for a small number of clients and low throughput, using one thread per client is simplest.)

Answer (score 3):

> The documentation says multiple clients can connect to a single pipe instance

No, it doesn't.  You misread what it actually said.

> but then proceeds to talk about multiple instances.

Each pipe instance can only communicate with one client at a time.  When the client is finished, the server can either disconnect the instance and reuse it for a new client, or it can destroy the instance and create a new instance.  Either way, the server must create a separate pipe instance for each client that connects.

> 1.For a small number of clients and low throughput, which is the simplest: 1 thread, 1 pipe instance; 1 thread and multiple pipe instances; multiple threads and one instance per thread?

The first way only allows for 1 client at a time.

The second way allows the server to create multiple instances for handling simultaneous connections, but requires overlapped I/O be used so 1 thread can manage the multiple connections.

The third way also allows the server to create multiple instances for handling simultaneous connections, but is the simplest as the server can run each instance in its own thread, servicing whichever client is currently connected to that instance. Overlapped I/O is not needed.

> 2.If a single thread does ConnectNamedPipe multiple times on the same instance of a pipe, does this mean a single WriteFile is broadcast to all clients that have connected to that particular instance of the pipe?
>
> 3.If multiple clients can connect to a particular instance of a pipe, does writing to that pipe from the server side block until all the clients have read the previous message?

No and no, because multiple clients cannot be connected to a single instance at the same time.

> 4.Is doing a one-to-many situation uncommon?

One-to-many is not possible with named pipes.  But you can have multiple simultaneous one-to-one connections, and it is not uncommon to broadcast data amongst multiple connections.  In this case, you are best of using a separate thread with each connection, or overlapped I/O.  This way, if one client does block, other clients are not blocked waiting on it.